# How to download a file from a presigned S3 link using PHP GuzzleHttp?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, guzzle

I'm using Lob to send physical mail to clients, and I'm provided a pre-signed S3 asset link which is a PDF of the letter that I just sent.

I'd like to load this PDF into memory and attach it to an email, however, I'm getting a strange error when trying to download using GuzzleHttp. Here's my code:

```
$url = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[letter id].pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=[aws access key]&Expires=[expiration]&Signature=[signature]'
$response = (new \GuzzleHttp\Client)->get($url); 
$pdf = $response->getBody();
```

This results in an error of:

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
Client error: `GET https://s3-us-west-
2.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[letter id].pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=[access key]&Expires=[expiration]&Signature=[signature]` resulted in a `404 Not Found` 
response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.
</Message><Key>[letter id].pdf</Key>
<RequestId>[request id]</RequestId>
<HostId>[host id]</HostId></Error>
```

The strange thing is when I access the URL in my browser, everything works completely fine.

Something is going wrong here, I'm assuming it's a caveat with AWS. I've never used AWS before. The pdf is accessible by anyone who has the link, so shouldn't I be able to get it using Guzzle?

The link isn't expired. It has a 30 day expiration date.

Comment: Why not try file_get_contents($url). Can you give the link you're trying to download?

Comment: @altoids I get an error: file_get_contents([encoded url]): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. I don't know how it's 404 not found. Could it be due to the encoding of the URL?

Comment: Are you sure your $url is correct? print it on the console and check it.